# Add an object to an arraylist using reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I have this setup

```
public class ClassA {   
    //I cannot modify or access this class
    private List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();  
}

public class ClassB {

    public void entry(String... args) {
        ClassA instance = ClassRegistry.find(ClassA.class); 
        //add using reflection
        //instance.list.add(new Object());
    }
}
```

how do I add an object to that list using reflection?

I tried

```
Field list = instance.getClass().getDeclaredField("list");
list.setAccessible(true);
ArrayList<Object> actualList = (ArrayList<Object>) list.get(instance);
actualList.add(new Object());
list.set(instance, actualList);
```

but it didn't work. the list was still empty.

Comment: Unable to reproduce. See [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/S55UR4). Note that it's safer to just cast to `List`, not `ArrayList`, and that you don't need to update the field, so the `set()` call is unnecessary.

Comment: The question you should ponder is: How do you know that the list of the same instance of `ClassA` is still empty? Perhaps you checked a difference instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the instances were indeed different, thanks to whoever pointed that out.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work. Have a look at the code sample

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ReflectionApp {

    private static ClassA classA = new ClassA();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalArgumentException,
            IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
        ClassB classB = new ClassB();
        classB.entry("Foo", "Bar");
    }

    public static class ClassA {
        //I cannot modify or access this class

        private List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "ClassA{" + "list=" + list + '}';
        }

    }

    public static class ClassB {

        public void entry(String... args) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalArgumentException,
                IllegalAccessException {
            ClassA instance = classA;
            // Do the reflection
            Field list = instance.getClass().getDeclaredField("list");
            list.setAccessible(true);
            ArrayList<Object> actualList = (ArrayList<Object>) list.get(instance);
            for( Object arg : args ){
                actualList.add(arg);
            }
            list.set(instance, actualList);
            System.out.println(actualList);
            System.out.println(classA);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

you can try the code below

```
ClassA instance = new ClassA();
Field list = ClassA.class.getDeclaredField("list");
list.setAccessible(true);
ArrayList<Object> actualList = (ArrayList<Object>) list.get(instance);
actualList.add(new Object());
list.set(instance, actualList);
```

Comment: If you don't create an instance of `ClassA`, where did `instance` come from?

Comment: i did miss understood the question